# Shapefile lines disappear, but data remains

Tags: qgis, shapefile, linestring

I'm working in QGIS 3.4 on a line type shapefile layer with +/-5000 records.  I made an edit to the start/end nodes of a couple of lines to move them to a point node from another layer; then when I saved my line layer, half of the lines from that layer disappeared from my canvas.  The records still exist in the attribute table, I can select them based on their values, but it appears as if the geometry has gone null - even with a record selected, I can not zoom or flash features.

Comment: what kind of file format was it ?

Comment: shapefile.  I've been working with this data for weeks with no problems.

Comment: Did you edit, delete, or rename any of the component files of the shapefile (the .DBF, .SHX, etc.) outside of GIS? Editing the DBF in Excel or something can cause problems like this.

Comment: No changes other than a simple vertex edit to snap two lines to node from another layer.

Comment: I've added a virtual field to the attribute table to identify the starting x coordinate of the lines, only 1224 of 4496 records have a value; so 3272 records have randomly lost their geometry... I haven't found any tools or articles on how to recover geometry in a case like this.

Comment: Do you have a back up copy of the shapefile?

Comment: I did get a backup of the shapefile and restored it using that, but I did lose half a day's work and am still unsure of what caused the geometry loss or if there is a better way to recover the geometry if it should happen again.